# Where firefox stores data shown in resource:///defaults/preferences/firefox.js?

Tags: firefox

When I open url resource:///defaults/preferences/firefox.js in Firefox 45.0, it shows many options that according to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences) should be stored in browser/app/profile/firefox.js

But the only files I see in my firefox browser directory are:

```
blocklist.xml  
chrome.manifest  
crashreporter-override.ini  
icons    
searchplugins
chrome         
components       
extensions                  
omni.ja
```

Tried to find it on both Linux and MacOS.

So where does this data comes from?

**UPDATE**:
This is the output of latest linux version of firefox (45.0)

```
root@ip-172-30-0-227:/tmp/fireomni# unzip -l omni.ja | grep firefox.js
warning [omni.ja]:  11393365 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [omni.ja]:  reported length of central directory is
  -11393365 bytes too long (Atari STZip zipfile?  J.H.Holm ZIPSPLIT 1.1
  zipfile?).  Compensating...
     9581  2010-01-01 00:00   modules/commonjs/sdk/tabs/tab-firefox.js
     2179  2010-01-01 00:00   modules/commonjs/sdk/tabs/tabs-firefox.js
    11658  2010-01-01 00:00   modules/commonjs/sdk/windows/firefox.js
     7785  2010-01-01 00:00   modules/commonjs/sdk/windows/tabs-firefox.js
     2510  2010-01-01 00:00   jsloader/resource/gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/tabs/tabs-firefox.js
    13372  2010-01-01 00:00   jsloader/resource/gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/windows/firefox.js
    12660  2010-01-01 00:00   jsloader/resource/gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/tabs/tab-firefox.js
     7573  2010-01-01 00:00   jsloader/resource/gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/windows/tabs-firefox.js
```

The firefox.js files listed here are not the one that shown in resource:///defaults/preferences/firefox.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the internal javascript and xml is packed in omni.ja, which is just a zip archive.

---

opening resource:///defaults/preferences/firefox.js contains, among many others, these lines:

```
//@line 1643 "c:\builds\moz2_slave\m-cen-w64-ntly-000000000000000\build\src\browser\app\profile\firefox.js"
pref("dom.ipc.reportProcessHangs", true);
```

`strings browser/omni.ja | grep "//@line 1643"` matches

also

```
# unzip -l browser/omni.ja | grep firefox.js
warning [browser/omni.ja]:  30524217 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [browser/omni.ja]:  reported length of central directory is
  -30524217 bytes too long (Atari STZip zipfile?  J.H.Holm ZIPSPLIT 1.1
  zipfile?).  Compensating...
    82905  2010-01-01 00:00   defaults/preferences/firefox.js
```

So the data is definitely in there.

Comment: I've unpacked the omni.ja file, but there is no firefox.js file too. Maybe it's values compiled in build time and stored hardcoded inside firefox binary?

Comment: I've updated the question. Still can't find firefox.js :(

Comment: Thank you, didn't think there is couple of omni.ja files.